# How to use JasperReports with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports, spring-4

I've been investigating the use of JasperReports (6.0.0) with Spring MVC (4.1.3) to generate PDF reports. Spring is rife with "Spring specific" ways to integrate with JasperReports to generate PDFs:

- Use [`JasperReportsPdfView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/jasperreports/JasperReportsPdfView.html) *relies on now deprecated JasperReport features*
- Use [`JasperReportsMultiFormatView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/jasperreports/JasperReportsMultiFormatView.html)
- Use [`JasperReportsViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/jasperreports/JasperReportsViewResolver.html)

I struggled to find good, complete examples online and wanted to share my findings (see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27532493/225217)).

Feel free to add additional methods and/or improvements related to "How can I integrate JasperReports with Spring4"?

Comment: This is an example of using jasper report on a spring mvc project:

https://github.com/dihaw-team/dihaw-spring-jasperreports

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Based on my research, I've found the following usage methods. The methods begin with the most direct (naive) approach involving less up front complexity / configuration and evolve to become more abstract but with more dependencies on Spring / more complex Spring configuration.

### Method 1: Use the JasperReports API directly in the Controller

Just write out the content to the servlet output stream.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "helloReport1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public void getRpt1(HttpServletResponse response) throws JRException, IOException {
    InputStream jasperStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jasperreports/HelloWorld1.jasper");
    Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperStream);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());

    response.setContentType("application/x-pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=helloWorldReport.pdf");

    final OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outStream);
  }
```

---

### Method 2: Inject JasperReportPdf View into Controller

Given the JasperReportsPdfView bean:

```
@Bean @Qualifier("helloWorldReport2")
public JasperReportsPdfView getHelloWorldReport() {
  JasperReportsPdfView v = new JasperReportsPdfView();
  v.setUrl("classpath:jasperreports/HelloWorld2.jasper");
  v.setReportDataKey("datasource");
  return v;
}
```

This view can be injected or wired into the Controller for use:

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("helloWorldReport2")
private JasperReportsPdfView helloReport;

@RequestMapping(value = "helloReport2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getRpt2(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
  Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<>();
  parameterMap.put("datasource", new JREmptyDataSource());
  modelAndView = new ModelAndView(helloReport, parameterMap);
  return modelAndView;
}
```

Note that using the `JasperReportsPdfView` (or the more versatile `JasperReportsMultiFormatView`) requires a dependency on spring-context-support:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

---

### Method 3: Use XML or ResourceBundle view resolver to map logical view names to JasperReport views

Configure a new view resolver, in this case the `ResourceBundleViewResolver` to run before the `InternalResourceViewResolver`.  This is based on the order values being set (0 happens before 1):

```
@Bean
public ResourceBundleViewResolver getResourceBundleViewResolver() {
  ResourceBundleViewResolver resolver = new ResourceBundleViewResolver();
  resolver.setBasename("jasperreport-views");
  resolver.setOrder(0);
  return resolver;
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
  resolver.setOrder(1);
  return resolver;
}
```

Then, at the root of our classpath, the `jasperreport-views.properties` file can contain the logical view name paired with the class and property values (i.e. url and reportDataKey) pertinent to rending a JasperReport:

```
helloReport3.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView
helloReport3.url=classpath:/jasperreports/HelloWorld3.jasper
helloReport3.reportDataKey=myDataSourceKey
```

The controller code looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "helloReport3", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getRpt3(ModelMap modelMap, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
  modelMap.put("myDataSourceKey", new JREmptyDataSource());
  return new ModelAndView("helloReport3", modelMap);
}
```

I like this approach. Controllers stay "dumb" and only deal with String values and the mapping of names to views can happen all in one location.

---

### Method 4: Use JasperReportsViewResolver

Configure a zero-ordered `JasperReportViewResolver` and the trick is use `setViewNames` to tell Spring which logical view names you want this resolver to deal with (otherwise you end up with "Could not load JasperReports report from class path resource [jasperreports/index.jasper]" type errors):

```
@Bean
public JasperReportsViewResolver getJasperReportsViewResolver() {
  JasperReportsViewResolver resolver = new JasperReportsViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/jasperreports/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jasper");
  resolver.setReportDataKey("datasource");
  resolver.setViewNames("rpt_*");
  resolver.setViewClass(JasperReportsMultiFormatView.class);
  resolver.setOrder(0);
  return resolver;
}  

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
  resolver.setOrder(1);
  return resolver;
}
```

And inside the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "helloReport4", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getRpt4(ModelMap modelMap, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
  modelMap.put("datasource", getWidgets());
  modelMap.put("format", "pdf");
  modelAndView = new ModelAndView("rpt_HelloWorld", modelMap);
  return modelAndView;
}
```

This is my preferred approach. Controllers resolve jasper reports in a very similar fashion to how jsp views are resolved using the `InternalResourceViewResolver` and there is therefore no need for an explicit mapping file as with the xml or properties file approach in method #3 above.

**EDIT**

The [javadocs for `JasperReportsPdfView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/jasperreports/JasperReportsPdfView.html) mention it uses the deprecated `JRExporter` API.  Is there a better (newer) JasperReports view to use?  Perhaps opting for the [`JasperReportsMultiFormatView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/jasperreports/JasperReportsMultiFormatView.html) is a better option as it does not appear to use `JRExporter`.

Comment: Helped me a lot a sample app I made using the same here https://github.com/gauravbrills/jasperreportswithspringboot

Comment: I've tried the method #4 for XLS and it works. However, the generated file has no extension. How to set the file name as well as the extension of the generated file using method #4?

Comment: @Brice Ronance : can you help me here? i am stuck at viewing my jasperreport http://stackoverflow.com/q/38390723/2666368

Comment: @Brice can you please tell me how "REPORT_VIRTUALIZER" will be use here

Comment: Thanks @Brice Roncace for your great explanation. I'm using the method 3 and I've always an empty pdf. Checking logs seems the modelview is not found from BeanNameViewResolver:74 - No matching bean found for view name 'blue'. Do you have advice? Thanks

Comment: @Brice I am using the method 1 but my report doesn't get displayed. there are no error logs in the server or browser console. I can see in the mozilla browser firebug response tab that the pdf has come successfully. but it doesn't show in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

My Method:

```
   @RequestMapping(value="getPDF", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public void generatePDF(int idPredstave, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

    Predstava p = pr.findById(idPredstave).get();
    List<Uloga> uloge = ur.findByPredstava(p);

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(uloge);
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jasperreports/Uloge.jrxml");
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("nazivPredstave", p.getNaziv());
    params.put("trajanje", p.getTrajanje());
    params.put("opis", p.getOpis());
    params.put("zanr", p.getZanr().getNaziv());
    params.put("reziser", p.getReziser().getIme()+" "+p.getReziser().getPrezime());
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);
    inputStream.close();


    response.setContentType("application/x-download");
    response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Uloge.pdf");
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,out);
}
```