# How to integrate jasperreports_extension.properties with Spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

`jasperreports_extension.properties` can use as external configuration file to customize default font and other parameters, however I found little document regarding how to integrate this file into Spring framework, i.e. from any method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532446/how-to-use-jasperreports-with-spring-mvc) thread.

Basically I am trying to define the default fonts to my current Jasper report dynamically by `jasperreports_extension.properties`, I have everything works except don't know where to put this properties file and connect it with my Spring jasper bean.

Comment: Hey Dreamer, have you found any solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great news Dreamer! I managed to solve this problem.

What you need to do is add the jasperreports-fonts jar into your classpath, for example, using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This will take care of everything, however, you will only have the DejaVu font available. So in your report you can add the following to have bold fonts:

```
<font fontName="DejaVu Sans" isBold="true"/>
```

You can check the available font names inside the `net.sj.jasperreports.fonts.fonts.xml` file inside the jar. If DejaVu doesn't move your boat, you can always follow [this guide](http://grysz.com/2010/06/01/use-custom-fonts-in-jasperreports-pdf-exporter/) for adding more fonts in the jar.

I truly hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and I feel that the answer is actually:

"**Extension registry**

JasperReports looks for available extensions by loading all the jasperreports_extension.properties files that it can find **in the default package**."

taken from documentation: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/extensions/package-summary.html

kindest regards,

John (@codingdude)